# 初期条件を入力したときに値ではなく可視化された図を出力するモデルを作りたい

Tags: python, 機械学習

プログラミング初心者で使用言語はPythonです。
やりたいことは以下の通りです。

1. ランダムに障害物が配置されてる仮想水路を設定
2. 色んな流量を流して平面2次元の計算をさせて流速ベクトルを可視化する(カルマン渦とかをみたい)
3. 結果を畳み込みニューラルネットワークで学習
4. 学習結果から次のようなことをしたい
   任意の場所に障害物を配置し、任意の流量を入力したときそれがどのような流れになるのか流速ベクトルで可視化された予想図を出力

教えていただきたい点

1. そもそも上記のような図を出力させる機械学習は可能なのか
2. Pythonだけで可能なのか(数値計算はjuliaなどにさせたり言語を分けた方がいいのでしょうか？)

一応LightGBMを使った2値予測なら少し経験があるのですが初期条件から流れの図をだすというのは経験がないため何から手をつけたらいいのかわかりません。
すみませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ニューラルネットワークへのインプットについてなのですが、仮想水路というのは、実物の装置に流体を流したもので、インプットはそれをカメラ撮影したものと、更に他のソフトでそれに流速ベクトルを加算合成したものでしょうか。また、ご質問は教師データ用の流速ベクトル生成ソフトの作成まで含んでいますか？（だからPythonだけで可能かの質問がある？）。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。cnnは入力も画像でないといけないのですね。先生にcnnでやってみてと軽く言われただけなのでまだ正確に理解できていませんでした。先生に言われていることをもう一度まとめると次のようなイメージです。深さを考慮しないでいいくらい浅い水路を仮定して障害物を配置した状態で流量を与えたときの流体計算を行います。その数値解析結果を可視化すると流線を見ることが出来ると思います。（流速に色付けできると有難いです）その結果を学習させ、インプットに流量を与えるとアウトプットとしてその時の水の流れが画像として出力されるというイメージです。なのでインプットは数値アウトプットは画像で考えていました。なおソフトの作成などは全く考えておりません。

Comment: 私は機械学習やベクトル演算はやりますが流体力学は詳しくないので機械学習の知識のみで答えますが、まず、CNNのインプットは通常は画像です。CNNの場合、恐らく色んな流量の時の画像が必要です。数値解析結果を可視化する部分はご自身で作成されるっぽいので、使うのはPythonと画像生成系ライブラリで十分そうですね。機械学習が可能かどうかは恐らく「仮想水路」がどんなものか次第だと思います。これは具体的にどんなものですか？CADなどの３Dソフトで生成されているなど、なんらかの方法で「流れの方向が見て分かる」画像にできるんでしょうか。

Comment: はい。数値解析結果の可視化はpythonでしようと思っています。『fortranかjulia(juliaは使ったことないので余裕があれば）で数値解析→pythonで可視化→学習→初期流量を入力→画像を可視化』をイメージしております。ご指摘を受けて、仮想水路をどうするか悩んでいたのですがよく考えると必要ないように思えてきました。仮想水路を作るというよりかはそのような水路になるように条件を設定すると解決すると思います。x, y, zで条件付けをしたうえで初期流量と初期流速を入力して数値計算を行い可視化→学習というふうにしようと考えています。

Comment: うーん。manatsuさんが端折って書かれているので無ければ、CNNを使う場合はイメージされているステップを修正する必要があると思います。AIというのは、最新の特殊なものを除いてインプットの形式は変更できません。つまり、学習の時は画像が入力で、予測の時は流量などの数値を入力するということは出来ないです。
私がCNNでやるとしたら、「初期流量と水路パラメータを入力→条件を数値解析→条件からAIのインプット用の画像を生成→Pythonで流速ベクトルを可視化して画像に書き込み→AIを、流速ベクトルを書き込んだ画像と書き込んで無い画像を使って、流速ベクトルをどのように自動生成したらいいか分かるようにトレーニング」までが第一段階です。
そして、実際の予測では「初期流量と水路パラメータを入力→条件からAIのインプット用の画像を生成→AIで流速ベクトルを予測→Pythonでインプット画像に予測した流速ベクトルを書き込み」という感じか、オートエンコーダのように直接画像を生成できるものを使うのであれば、「初期流量と水路パラメータを入力→条件からAIのインプット用の画像を生成→AIで流速ベクトルが書き込まれた画像ファイルを出力」となります。

Comment: ただ、手動入力できる程度のパラメータ数なのであれば、CNNを使わず、初期条件と数値計算の結果をMLPなどに学習させて、Pythonで画像として書き出すことができそうな気がしますし、AI無しでPythonや他の言語で直接ベクトル計算をやったほうが早いような気もします。これは、数値解析後Pythonで可視化して終了ということです。

Comment: 念の為追記ですが、「先生にCNNでやってみて」と言われているということでしたので、これは課題かなにかで、manatsuさんや先生の研究内容だったり、レターとして出す予定の可能性探索研究などでは無いですよね・・・？
先にここに情報が出てしまったら論文や特許に影響が出たりするものだったら、ここで私が詳しい解法を考えると良くない可能性がありますからご注意ください。なお、これまでの私のコメントは本に載っているようなレベルの一般的な回答なので影響ないと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。これは授業の課題ではあるのですが別にできなくてもいいよと言われているので研究に結び付けるようなことは全く考えていません。色々問題点などがわかってきて有難いです。CNNでは少し難しいなと感じているので学習方法を少し見直してみようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: いえいえ。良かったです。
このご質問は「機械学習＋流体力学」ということで、ジャンルが２つ融合しているため結構回答できる技術者が減ると思います。
掛け合わせるほどレアスキルになるので。
なので、このご質問の回答をご自身で出来るようになった時にまだ回答がついていなければ、シンプルなセルフ回答で閉じられると良いかもしれません。ではでは。